Failed to Resolve Dependency: org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006 in Kotlin
I'm trying to add the WebRTC library to my Android project, but I'm encountering an issue with resolving the dependency. Here's the relevant part of my build.gradle.kts file:
dependencies {
    implementation("org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006")
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
}

I tried the methods of this question which was asked previously on stackoverflow but It is not fixing
Please help I am stuck on this for around 4 days
I was expecting that this dependency would install

This question is similar to: How to fix "Failed to resolve: org.webrtc:google-webrtc"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I asked this as previous one was not working

Have you considered that using a binary artifact of a library that has intentionally not received updates, including security updates, for four years is not a good idea?

@PhilippHancke any alternative or solution you want to provide?

Yes I had the same problem this is deprecated now.
You can check here from MavenCentral repo
This one is the replacement
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.dafruits/webrtc

In that case you can use this library. Its updated and its from reputed contributors https://github.com/GetStream/webrtc-android

I replace implementation
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'

with
implementation 'com.infobip:google-webrtc:1.0.0035529'

and That's Works fine !
